# ColdFusion DrawImage Antialising still hard edgy

Tags: coldfusion, fonts

I know hard edgy is the wrong word. I think pixalated? But w/e the word is, i hope you cna understand that. Basically if i draw the text onto an image in Coldfusion without anti alising the text looks pixely and not smooth like it would in flash or something (i do understand flash is vector based hence the smoothness), however with AntiAlising turned on, ColdFusion still shows it pixely however less now. How can i achevie a smoooth font effect with dynamic text and fonts.

The project is to take a font and generate text from it.

Comment: i think "jaggy" is the common term.

Comment: Can you post some screenshots?

Comment: Some code samples and images might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's just how ColdFusion and CFImage work. You're not going to get smooth flash vector-style text, because you're drawing with JPG and GIF formats. Turning on anti-aliasing is the best you're going to get for doing text with cfimage.

Dan

Comment: Thanks, ive started to look into other image solutions